# how to toggle children element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have parent button with `<i>` tag element as a children, which is, if i click the button class they will be trigger the toggle class for both parent and child so it set the condition active and inactive button if i move one button to the other, the problem is my toggle class for child element is not working when i click the active button it self, the check icon won't disappear. here is my code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hggk6348/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').on("click", function() {
    $('.price-filter-active').not(this).removeClass('price-filter-active');
    $('.fa').removeClass('fa-check');

    $(this).toggleClass('price-filter-active');
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-check');
  })
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {
  width: 1190px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.price-filter-active {
  background: #42B549;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <button class="span2 button">
           1
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            2
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            3
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
          4
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the issue with the code at Question? What is expected result?

Comment: when i click the active button the check icon should be disappear, my code only can remove the green color but the check icon still in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.button').on("click", function() {

  $('.price-filter-active').not(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-check');
  $('.price-filter-active').not(this).removeClass('price-filter-active');
  $(this).toggleClass('price-filter-active');
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-check');
 
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {
  width: 1190px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.price-filter-active {
  background: #42B549;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-filter-container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <button class="span2 button">
           1
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            2
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            3
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
          4
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not loading neither jQuery nor font-awesome in your fiddle, here is it working :

```js
$('.button').on("click", function() {
  $('.price-filter-active').not(this).removeClass('price-filter-active');
  $('.fa').not($(this).find('.fa')).removeClass('fa-check');
  $(this).toggleClass('price-filter-active');
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-check');
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {
  width: 1190px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.price-filter-active {
  background: #42B549;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="price-filter-container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <button class="span2 button">
      1
      <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="span2 button">
      2
      <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="span2 button">
      3
      <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="span2 button">
      4
      <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i already update my fiddle, and it's still not working , - when i try to click the active button (the green button with check icon), the color will change to non active but the check icon still leave (it should be disappear also)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were missing including jQuery, which defines $. After including jQuery and fontawesome libraries to your fiddle, things seem to be working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hggk6348/3/

Answer (score 1):

change this line `$('.fa').removeClass('fa-check');` 
to
 `$('.price-filter-active').not(this).find("i").removeClass('fa-check');`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').on("click", function() {
    
    $('.price-filter-active').not(this).removeClass('price-filter-active');
    $('.price-filter-active').not(this).find("i").removeClass('fa-check');

    $(this).toggleClass('price-filter-active');
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('fa-check');
  })
})
```

```css
.price-filter-container {
  width: 1190px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.price-filter-active {
  background: #42B549;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="price-filter-container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <button class="span2 button">
           1
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            2
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
            3
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <button class="span2 button">
          4
            <i class="fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```